# Monitoring network transfer of a certain program

Tags: networking, sniffing

I need to monitor the data transfer of a program (Unity3D).

I'm looking for a program that would show when request were made and the content of them. Something similar to the Network tab of Chrome's Developer Tools would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereal was good for this kind of stuffs. [found it here](http://www.ethereal.com/)

Comment: Thanks! WireShark is quite a powerful tool!

Comment: yes, WireShark is as good as Ethereal. Still I prefer the latter, guess because is the first I've ever used.

Comment: I thought they are the same, because the download link from Ethereal links me to WireShark

Comment: Ethereal was initially a library. WireShark uses it. But I prefer the original UI